# Аутентификация Laravel, не срабатывает Auth::attempt

Tags: php, laravel, ооп, mvc, orm

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Не получается сделать вход. Роуты:

```
Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@admin_page');
Route::post('/admin/panel', 'AdminController@authenticate');
```

AdminController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AdminController extends Controller
{

    public function admin_page()
    {   
        return view('admin/admin-panel');
    }

    public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        $name = Request::input('name');
        $password = Request::input('password');

        $credentials = Request::only('name', 'password');
        var_dump($credentials);


        if (Auth::attempt(['name' => $name, 'password' => $password])) {
            // Аутентификация успешна...
            return redirect()->intended('category');
            echo "yes";
        }
        else{
            echo "no";
        }


    }

}
```

Форма:

```
<form class="comment-area" method="POST" action="/admin/panel" id="form">
                            {{csrf_field()}}
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Your Name">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Your email address">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Your password">
                                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="вход">
                            </form>
```

Модель User:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{

    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

В ответ получаю no... Укажите на ошибку пожалуйста.

Comment: а зачем вам самим это реализовывать, если всё уже реализовано?

Comment: 1. Проверьте свою модель пользователя, вероятно у вас колонки не сходятся (name, email). 2. Auth::attempt проверяет данные пользователя, а не авторизирует его. Для входа необходимо использовать Auth::login.

Comment: `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` Вроде так правильно

Comment: @DanielProtopopov attempt проверяет и аутентифицирует пользователя.

Comment: Auth::login тоже не работает, добавил модель User в вопрос

Comment: @IndianCoding да, был не прав

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Auth::attempt([
           'name' => $request->get('name'),
           'password' => $request->get('password'),
       ]))
```

попробуй так написать свою проверку

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::get()  Ошибка